# Formatting multidimensional array from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, multidimensional-array

My application receives JSON from forms in this format:

```
{"loc[criteria][0][row][0][field]":"120","loc[criteria][0][row][0][chan]":"any","loc[criteria][0][row][0][network]":"any","loc[criteria][0][row][0][op]":"lt","loc[criteria][0][row][0][value]":"","loc[criteria][0][match]":"all","loc[match]":"all"}
```

When I run json_decode($json, TRUE) on that, I get a single-dimensional array:

```
 Array (
[loc[criteria][0][row][0][field]] => 120
[loc[criteria][0][row][0][chan]] => any
[loc[criteria][0][row][0][network]] => any
[loc[criteria][0][row][0][op]] => lt
[loc[criteria][0][row][0][value]] =>
[loc[criteria][0][match]] => all
[loc[match]] => all    
)
```

The input can get much larger, with many rows and criterias.  I'd like to convert the JSON into a multidimensional array like so:

```
 Array (
 criteria => Array (
      0 => Array (
        row => Array (
           0 => Array (
              field => 120
... etc...
```

What would be a proper way to convert this?

-- Update --

The input comes from serializing a form created by Symfony2.  Here's the javascript:

```
var array = $('#search-form').serializeArray();
var json = {};

jQuery.each(array, function() {
    json[this.name] = this.value || '';
});

var ajaxInput=JSON.stringify(json);  //this is what gets passed to the server
```

This is an example of a field generated by the Symfony2 form:

```
<input type="text" id="loc_criteria_0_row_0_value" name="loc[criteria][0][row][0][value]" placeholder="Value">
```

Comment: Paste the code where you are making this transformation

Comment: Why don't you properly encode this in JSON? Then you'd only have to decode

Comment: @kingkero is correct, what you are starting out with is not valid JSON. if you fix that, you should fix your issue

Comment: Indeed. While it's possible to write a solution for this, the real answer should be to do this properly before the JSON gets encoded at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

```
$output_array = parse_json_input_form_array('{"loc[criteria][0][row][0][field]":"120","loc[criteria][0][row][0][chan]":"any","loc[criteria][0][row][0][network]":"any","loc[criteria][0][row][0][op]":"lt","loc[criteria][0][row][0][value]":"","loc[criteria][0][match]":"all","loc[match]":"all"}');

function parse_json_input_form_array($json) {
    $decoded_array = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach ($decoded_array as $key => $value) {
        $items[] = urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
    }

    $items = implode("&", $items);

    parse_str($items, $parsed_items);

    return $parsed_items;
}
```